# MySQL Query filter result

Tags: mysql, sql

Bellow are my tables with data,

1) **product**

```
id    name    
------------
1     abc
2     def
3     xyz
```

2) **product_attribute**

```
id    product_id  attribute_id  attribute_value_id    
--------------------------------------------------
1     1           1             1
2     1           1             2
3     1           2             4
4     2           1             3
5     2           2             5
6     3           1             1
7     1           3             6
```

3) **attribute**

```
id    name
---------------
1     color        
2     size
3     width
```

4) **attribute_value**

```
id    name
--------------
1     Red
2     Blue
3     Black
4     2.5
5     3.5
6     5
```

When finding the product which has a color = red then get a products 'abc' and 'xyz.

```
SELECT * 
FROM product AS p 
INNER JOIN product_attribute AS pa ON pa.p_id = p.id 
WHERE (pa.attribute_id = 1 AND pa.attribute_value_id IN(1)) 
GROUP BY p.id
```

**Question**

When finding the product which has a color = red and size = 2.5 then return zero results.

```
SELECT * 
FROM product AS p 
INNER JOIN product_attribute AS pa ON pa.p_id = p.id 
WHERE ((pa.attribute_id = 1 AND pa.attribute_value_id IN(1)) 
  AND (pa.attribute_id = 2 AND pa.attribute_value_id IN(4))) 
GROUP BY p.id
```

How can I get the product which has color = red and size = 2.5?

Comment: You can't use multiple where condition like this on same column because you dont have same column with value 1 and 2 at the instance. Sorry for the comment. I think you should create separate tables or columns instead for attrubute type, because you're gonna have to use much complex query later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are 2 ways using joins to get the products which matches all these attributes and values

Using count()

```
SELECT p.id,p.name  
FROM product p 
INNER JOIN product_attribute pa ON pa.product_id = p.id 
INNER JOIN attribute a ON a.id = pa.attribute_id
INNER JOIN attribute_value av ON av.id = pa.attribute_value_id
WHERE a.name IN('color','size')
AND av.name IN('red','2.5')
GROUP BY p.id,p.name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT a.id) = 2 
AND COUNT(DISTINCT av.id) = 2
```

By using sum()

```
SELECT p.id,p.name 
FROM product p 
INNER JOIN product_attribute pa ON pa.product_id = p.id 
INNER JOIN attribute a ON a.id = pa.attribute_id
INNER JOIN attribute_value av ON av.id = pa.attribute_value_id
GROUP BY p.id,p.name 
HAVING SUM(a.name = 'color' AND av.name = 'red') > 0
AND SUM(a.name = 'size' AND av.name = '2.5') > 0
```

[**DEMO**](http://rextester.com/LYMK19101)

Comment: Thanks, @MKhalidJunaid for the answer. you save my day. But this will take too much time compare then [this query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056349/3256891)

Comment: @MitulKoradiya This can be of i have used all joins like attribute table and value you can omit these from join if you now their relevant ids like in your query but i thought you need the products which has all these attributes but by looking your query it will return if any of the attributes exist not all

Comment: When we use more than 2 or 3 attributes with value then must use sum x(count number of filter used in a query) number of time in having then query take more execution time.

Answer (score 1):

Finally got the solutions

Using Count()

```
SELECT p.id,p.name 
FROM product p 
INNER JOIN product_attribute pa ON pa.product_id = p.id 
where (
    (pa.attribute_id = 1 AND pa.attribute_value_id IN(1)) 
    OR (pa.attribute_id = 2 AND pa.attribute_value_id IN(4))
)GROUP BY p.id 
HAVING COUNT(p.id) = 2
```

You just need to add a count of the filter(like color, size, width etc.).

ex. if you add extra filter width = 5 then you add COUNT(p.id) = 3 in having.

Comment: The where clause should be `where pa.attribute_id in(1,2) and pa.attribute_value_id in(1,4)`

Answer (score 0):

If your table is not large you can use exists

```
    SELECT * FROM product AS p 
            WHERE exists(select * from product_attribute AS pa where pa.p_id = p.id and pa.attribute_id = 1 AND pa.attribute_value_id = 1)  // color = red
                and exists(select * from product_attribute AS pa where pa.p_id = p.id and pa.attribute_id = 2 AND pa.attribute_value_id = 4) // size = 2.5
```

You can also using join but it is more complicated

```
SELECT * FROM product AS p 
        INNER JOIN product_attribute AS pa1 ON pa1.p_id = p.id and pa1.attribute_id = 1 AND pa1.attribute_value_id = 1   // color = red
        INNER JOIN product_attribute AS pa2 ON pa2.p_id = p.id and pa2.attribute_id = 2 AND pa2.attribute_value_id = 4  // size = 2.5
```

Comment: Is this possible to get a result without using a subquery?

Comment: I have updated answer with join solutions, but it is a little complicated. One more thing no need to `group by p.id` if table `product_attribute` doesn't have duplicate (product_id, attribute_id, attribute_value_id)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use a condition like `color = 'Red' and size = 2.5` I can suggest using a query with pivoting data like this:

```
select *
from (
    select p.id, p.name
        , max(case when a.name = 'color' then av.name end) color
        , max(case when a.name = 'size' then cast(av.name as decimal(12,2)) end) size
    from product_attribute pa
    left join product p on pa.product_id = p.id
    left join attribute a on pa.attribute_id = a.id
    left join attribute_value av on pa.attribute_value_id = av.id
    group by p.id, p.name ) t
where
    t.color = 'Red' and t.size = 2.5;
```

[**MySQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ea474c/5)